# Drupal 7 + Failed to create directory "public://print_pdf/print_pdf_tcpdf/cache" for print_pdf_tcpdf

Tags: drupal-7

Drupal 7 + Failed to create directory

> public://print_pdf/print_pdf_tcpdf/cache

for print_pdf_tcpdf with S3fs module, when we replace "`public://`" folder to "`s3fs-public://`" on s3fs module setting page.

This setting directly upload the files to s3 public directory.

Module: print module

Answer (score 0):

Check the **location** and **permissions** for your files directory as specified by the Drupal 7 docs -see link below. Also, you can check the status from the performance section /admin/config..........

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/install/setting-up-the-files-directory

Comment: I am using S3 for Public directory and this is print module issues which not allow to upload files on correct location. please let me know if you need any more details.